# dnsmasq in Docker container often not receiving replies

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq

I have dnsmasq running in a docker container (Docker Desktop on Mac)

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  dns:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: strm/dnsmasq
    container_name: dnsmasq
    volumes:
      - $PWD/etc/dnsmasq.conf:/etc/dnsmasq.conf
      - $PWD/etc/myHosts:/etc/myHosts
      - $PWD/logs/dnsmasq:/logs/dnsmasq
    ports:
     - "53:53/udp"
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    entrypoint:
      tail
    command:
      -F anything
```

For this testing setup I then start a terminal in the container and run something like

`dnsmasq -d -q --log-queries=extra 2>> /logs/dnsmasq/2023-07-05_log2.txt`

/etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
#Define Port
port=53
domain-needed
bogus-priv

#dont use hosts nameservers
no-resolv

# Use the default nameservers
server=1.1.1.1

# domain to keep local
local=/rubik/

addn-hosts=/etc/myHosts
```

`/etc/myHosts` defines a few local IP addresses

It works in general, but requests keep on going unanswered and timing out with no pattern that I can discern. This is true for "real life" web browsing traffic, as well as `dig` queries for well know sites. It doesn't take long to find a domain, which doesn't get answered right away and eventually times out

I have the logs for one day in front of me, let's take `d.dropbox.com` as an example

402 `query[A]` entries, 9 `query[type=65]` entries, 411 `forwarded` entries (that checks out so far)

74 `reply` entries, 0 `cached` entries

As the replies are coming through sometimes I am not sure where to start my investigation. What could be the issue? Or is what I am seeing normal behaviour? This is my first foray into the world of DNS